# Move focus to another widget when the return or right arrow key is pressed?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I have a Qt widget that looks like this:

```
class launchiiwidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.textbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.textbox.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.textbox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)   
        self.textbox.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 100))
        self.textbox.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textbox.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        
        layout.addWidget(self.textbox)

        font = self.textbox.font()
        font.setPointSize(80)
        self.textbox.setFont(font)

        self.listwidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        self.listwidget.addItem("Red")
        self.listwidget.addItem("Blue") 
        layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = launchiiwidget()
    widget.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    widget.resize(600, 200)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

How can I make it so when the "return" or "right arrow key" is pressed, focus moves from wherever it is currently to the first item in `listwidget`? This should also work while being focused inside of textbox, without triggering a newline.

Note: items get dynamically added to listwidget.

Comment: Please fix the indentation, and also provide the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've fixed the issues, sorry!

Comment: @WoaItsBren  QListWidget doesn't have any items so what do you mean by *first item in listwidget*?

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry, items get dynamically added to qlistwidget, i've added some placeholders!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution could be to use QShorcut but because the OP requires "without triggering a newline". So in this case the solution is to implement an eventfilter to the QWindow:

```py
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class KeyHelper(QtCore.QObject):
    pressed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, window):
        super().__init__(window)
        self._window = window

        self.window.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def window(self):
        return self._window

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.KeyPress:
            if event.key() in (
                QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Return,
                QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Enter,
                QtCore.Qt.Key.Key_Right,
            ):
                self.pressed.emit()
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class Launchiiwidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.textbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.textbox.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.LineWrapMode.NoWrap)
        self.textbox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.textbox.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 100))
        self.textbox.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff
        )
        self.textbox.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
            QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff
        )

        font = self.textbox.font()
        font.setPointSize(80)
        self.textbox.setFont(font)

        self.listwidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listwidget.addItem("Red")
        self.listwidget.addItem("Blue") 

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textbox)
        layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)

    def update_focus(self):
        self.listwidget.setFocus()
        index = self.listwidget.model().index(0, 0)
        if index.isValid():
            self.listwidget.setCurrentIndex(index)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = Launchiiwidget()
    widget.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
    widget.resize(600, 200)
    widget.show()

    key_helper = KeyHelper(widget.windowHandle())
    key_helper.pressed.connect(widget.update_focus)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```